# How do I send this post data as JSON with Python request?

Tags: python, json, post, request, postdata

I try this post data send python with request json

```
{"APIRequests":[{"ApplicationId":"com.xsd.v1.1","Name":"JACK","SurName":"DANIEL","Verb":"Authenticate"}]}
```

I am trying to send like this

```
    oturum = requests.Session()
    headers = {
        'Host': 'www.xsd.com',
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'User-Agent': 'okhttp/3.12.1'}

    datapost= {'APIRequests': {'ApplicationId': "com.xsd.v1.1", 'Name': JACK, 'SurName':DANIEL,'Verb':'Authenticate'}}

    req = oturum.post("https://www.xsd.com/api/", headers=headers, json=datapost)

    print(req.json())
```

```
{'ServerTime': 'Tue, 08 Nov 2022 10:12:28 -0600', 'APIVersion': '11.2', 'Status': 'Error', 'ErrorCode': 6, 'ErrorMessage': 'The API requests are invalid.'}
```

```
    print(req.request.body)
```

```
b'{"APIRequests": {"ApplicationId": "com.xsd.v1.1", "Name": "JACK", "SurName": "DANIEL", "Verb": "Authenticate"}}'
```

But it's not right not working. Help please. Thank you

And why there is "b" in request body? is it normal?

Comment: Shouldn't you be printing req.json() rather than datapost.json() ?
Anyway, feel free to explain a bit more, can you say what is not working ? do you have any error message ?

Comment: Post data is sent incorrectly." ErrorMessage': 'The API requests are invalid." There is no problem when sending the same data from another application.

Comment: b in request body just mean the response is a byte string. Nothing to worry about.
I tried your piece of code but couldn't manage to make it work (not the same error as you.). The only potential problem here to me is JACK and DANIEL missing quotes but they might just be variables you declared earlier

Comment: Is the data I want to send the same as the data I am sending? If even one character is wrong, it should give an error.

Comment: @bymechul What API service are you using? There is probably some information about it in the reference.